# Check if Dict Item Exists - If Yes Then Compare And Keep Lower Value

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, lookup

I have two sheets in the same workbook.  The first sheet is called "Source" and the second is called "Result".  On "Source" I have a unique ID in Column CJ.  On "Result" I have my ID in Column H.  "Source" has dates in column O.  I am attempting to load data from "Source" into a dictionary.  When I load rows, I am attempting to check if it already exists in the dictionary.  If it DOES, I need to compare the dates which had the same ID and store only the lower value (earliest date).

EX.

```
Row 1 ID: 123ABC    Date: Dec 10, 2017
Row 2 ID: 123ABC    Date: Dec 15, 2017
Row 3 ID: 123ABC    Date: Dec 5, 2017
```

The macro should load 123ABC with Dec 10, 2017 then on the next row check and find that 123ABC exist and KEEP Dec 10 as the only 123ABC value.  On the next row, check and REPLACE Dec 10 with Dec 5 as the only value for 123ABC.

Once the dictionary is completed, I am doing a lookup which will retrieve the date based on the ID.  This lookup will use the ID in Column H on "Result" as it's "Lookup Value" and place the date into Column S of "Result".

The code I have thus far is below:

```
Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowForDict As Long, LastRowResult As Long, shtSource As Worksheet, shtResult As Worksheet


Set shtSource = Worksheets("Source")
Set shtResult = Worksheets("Result")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'load ID and Start dates to dictionary from Source Sheet

With shtSource
    LastRowForDict = .Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = .Range("CJ2:CJ" & LastRowForDict).Value
    x2 = .Range("O2:O" & LastRowForDict).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
        If dict.Exists(x(i, 1)) Then

        'compare two values which shared the same key and replace existing value if new value is smaller

    Next i


End With


'map the values
With shtResult
    LastRowResult = .Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = .Range("H2:H" & LastRowResult).Value    'looks up to this range
    ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)   '<< size the output array
    For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If dict.Exists(y(i, 1)) Then
            y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
        Else
            y2(i, 1) = "0"
        End If
    Next i
    .Range("S2:S" & LastRowResult).Value = y2  '<< place the output on the sheet
End With
```

I am having trouble with the comparison portion of the code. Which I think I started correctly with the line `If dict.Exists(x(i, 1)) Then`.  I am not sure if there are other issues as well?  Any assistance would be much appreciated.  I searched but couldn't find much on comparing dict items.

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: After executing the statement `dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)` then you **know** that `dict.Exists(x(i, 1))` will be `True` - the previous line created it if it didn't previously exist..  I suspect you want your `If` statement processing to precede the statement setting the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
    Else
        dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = Application.Min(dict.Item(x(i, 1)), x2(i, 1))
    End If
Next i
```